# is using Bootstrap grid system is better than using css3 media queries?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap grid system in my website in order to achieve responsive layout
i'm having problems with the margin and the font size since there is no break point 
like CSS3 media queries.
is using the bootstrap grid system means that there is no reason to use CSS3 media queries??
or should i use the both??
and answers will be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Bootstrap uses media queries, so i dont think you need to use media queries again.

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints should be defined based on content.

Bootstraps grid system is just a set of defaults, defaults that will not apply to all (or perhaps most) use cases.

You need to use the grid system in conjuction with media queries that are right-sized for your use case.